# What does this regular expression mean? (^.)(\w+)(.$) $2

Tags: c#, regex

`(^.)(\w+)(.$) $2` removes first and last char, but I'm not sure how does it work.

My understanding:

(^.) match any one character at the start of the line.
(.$) match any one character at the end of the line.
(\w+) any word character(at least one character is required)
$2 calls the second parentheses  (\w+)

Test1:

```
Input: 91239

Output: 123
```

Test2:

```
Input: \123\

Output: 123
```

Why does it remove the backslash? Is this a acceptable way to remove the backslash(begin and end of the line)?

Test3:

```
Input: /123/5

Output: /123/5
```

I'm lost here. Why it doesn't work for /123/5.

Thank you!

Comment: `\w` matches alphanumeric or underscore, not your slashes

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but it removed the backslashes. I don't know why

Comment: Your command is apparently replacing `(^.)(\w+)(.$)` with `$2` - the contents of the middle set of parens.

Comment: @Michael: Do you just want to remove arbitrary 1st and last character in the string? You do not need any regex for this.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it remove the backslash? Is this a acceptable way to remove the backslash(begin and end of the line)?

It removes the backslashes because `.` matches any character, including `\`. Group 1 is the first backslash, group 2 is every character but the first and last, group 3 is the last backslash.

> I'm lost here. Why it doesn't work for /123/5.

`\w` matches 0-9, a-z, A-Z, and _. `\w+` consumes `123`. The following `.` consumes `/`. The following `$` doesn't match the remaining `5`, thus there is no match with that input.

Comment: Thanks. Now  if I only want to remove the the first and last backslashes, what is regular express look like? (^\\)(\w+)((\\$) $2?

Comment: It should be something like `(^\\)(\w+)(\\$)` (with ```\\``` in the front)

Comment: If we're talking about removing the first and last backslashes from any arbitrary string, i.e., the backslashes don't have to be the first and last characters and anything in between doesn't need to match `\w`, it would be something like `(^[^\\])\\(.*)\\([^\\]*$) $1$2$3`.

Comment: To remove leading/trailing backslashes or any known character at an arbitrary position you do not need regex at all in C# and most other languages. Please edit your question with actual requirements, sample string, sample output, and criteria.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it doesn't work for /123/5.

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `.` matches any character.. so in `/123/5`.. `/` before `1` is matched by `^.` and `5` is matched by `.$` but `123/` is not matched since `/` is not a matched by `\w`

Regex `(^.)(\w+)(.$)` means (Explanation):

- `(^.)` start with any character (parenthesis => capture group 1)
- `(\w+)` followed by more than one `(+)` characters in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (parenthesis => capture group 2)
- `(.$)` end with any character (parenthesis => capture group 3)

And finally `$2` means backreference to capture group 2.. i.e group captured by pattern `(\w+)`.

Comment: Thanks. so, this (^\\)(\w+)(\\$) $2 means if the line start with \ and end with \, then capture the middle part if it only contains [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Am I correct?

Comment: @Michael Yes.. but it should be `(^\\)(\w+)(\\$) $2` .. with ```\\``` in front or else you will be escaping the parenthesis..

Comment: `$2` does not mean *capture group 2*, but a *back-reference* to the capture group 2. Capture group 2 is `(\w+)`. @Michael, you seem to change your regex from comment to comment: `$` is end of string/line, but `\$` is a *literal* `$` character. Please add your criteria in the question to get a clear and helpful answer.